# Enhanced for loop and Array

Tags: java, string, loops, arraylist, builder

```
public class modifyALelements {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    StringBuilder myArr [] = {new StringBuilder("One"), new StringBuilder("Two")};              
    
    for (StringBuilder val: myArr)
        System.out.println(val);
    
    for (StringBuilder val: myArr)
        val.append("Way");                                              
    
    for (StringBuilder val: myArr)
        System.out.println(val);

    StringBuilder anotherArr[] = { new StringBuilder("Java"), new StringBuilder("Loop") }; 

    for (StringBuilder element : anotherArr)
        System.out.println(element);

    for (StringBuilder element : anotherArr)
        element = new StringBuilder("Test");

    for (StringBuilder element : anotherArr)
        System.out.println(element);
    
    }
}
```

output:

```
One
Two
OneWay
TwoWay
Java
Loop
Java
Loop
```

Hi all,
Can someone please explain why has values of anotherArr not changed to Test last two for-each loops. When you use append() method, changes are applied e.g. OneWay and TwoWay.
Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In java, class types are reference types. This means that a variable of type `StringBuilder` will hold a *reference* to a `StringBuilder` object.

```
for (StringBuilder val: myArr)
    val.append("Way");
```

Here we take references from `myArr`. Then we call method `append`, which changes the referred object.

```
for (StringBuilder element : anotherArr)
    element = new StringBuilder("Test");
```

Here we also take a reference from an array. However, then we reassign a variable. This only changes what `element` variable refers to. No object is actually changed.